# Obtaining the element(s) that appears in 3 or more lists

Tags: python, list, comparison

Say I have 5 lists in total

```
# Sample data

a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

a2= [1,21,35,45,58]
a3= [1,2,15,27,36]
a4=[2,3,1,45,85,51,105,147,201]
a5=[3,458,665]
```

I need to find the elements of a1 which are also present in a2,a3,a4,a5 for more than 3 times including that in a1

or

I need the elements with frequency greater than or equal to 3 from all the lists (a1 - a5) combined, along with their frequency.

From the above example expected output  would be

1 with a frequency of 4

2 with a frequency of 3

3 with a frequency of 3

For my actual problem, the number of lists as well as the length are so huge, Can anyone suggest me a simple and fast approach ?

Thanks,

Prithivi

Comment: Look into `chain` from the `itertools` module and `Counter` from the `collections` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick writes in the comments, `chain` and `Counter` are your friends here:

```
import itertools
import collections

targets = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

lists = [
    [1,21,35,45,58],
    [1,2,15,27,36],
    [2,3,1,45,85,51,105,147,201],
    [3,458,665]
    ]

chained = itertools.chain(*lists)
counter = collections.Counter(chained)
result = [(t, counter[t]) for t in targets if counter[t] >= 2]
```

such that

```
>>> results
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
```

You say that you have a lot of lists, and each list is long. Try this solution and see how long it takes. If it needs to be sped-up, then that's another question. It may be that `collections.Counter` is too slow for your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
a1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a2= [1,21,35,45,58]
a3= [1,2,15,27,36]
a4= [2,3,1,45,85,51,105,147,201]
a5= [3,458,665]

b = a1+a2+a3+a4+a5                              #make b all lists together

for x in set(b):                                #iterate though b's set
    print(x, 'with a frequency of', b.count(x)) #print the count
```

will give you:

```
1 with a frequency of 4
2 with a frequency of 3
3 with a frequency of 3
4 with a frequency of 1
5 with a frequency of 1
6 with a frequency of 1
7 with a frequency of 1
35 with a frequency of 1
36 with a frequency of 1
...
```

Edit:

Using:

```
for x in range(9000):
    a1.append(random.randint(1,10000))
    a2.append(random.randint(1,10000))
    a3.append(random.randint(1,10000))
    a4.append(random.randint(1,10000))
```

I made the lists much much longer and using `time` I checked how long the program took(where it doesn't print but instead saves the info) and the program took 4.9395 seconds. I hope that is fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

This solution using pandas is quite fast

```
import pandas as pd

a1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a2=[1,21,35,45,58]
a3=[1,2,15,27,36]
a4=[2,3,1,45,85,51,105,147,201]
a5=[3,458,665]

# convert each list to a DataFrame with an indicator column
A = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
D = [ pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'ind{0}'.format(i):[1]*len(a)}) for i,a in enumerate(A)]

# left join each dataframe onto a1
# if you know the integers are distinct then you don't need drop_duplicates
df = pd.merge(D[0], D[1].drop_duplicates(['A']), how='left', on='A')
for d in D[2:]:
    df = pd.merge(df, d.drop_duplicates(['A']), how='left', on='A')

# sum accross the indicators
df['freq'] = df[['ind{0}'.format(i) for i,d in enumerate(D)]].sum(axis=1)

# drop frequencies less than 3
print df[['A','freq']].loc[df['freq'] >= 3]
```

A test using larger input below runs in well under 0.2 seconds on my machine

```
import numpy.random as npr
a1 = xrange(10000)
a2 = npr.randint(10000, size=100000) 
a3 = npr.randint(10000, size=100000) 
a4 = npr.randint(10000, size=100000) 
a5 = npr.randint(10000, size=100000)
```